# Can't find Correlation ID in Audit or Sign In Log

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I got reported an error including a correlation ID that I can't find in Sign In or Audit Logs in B2C.
I'm using B2C Custom Policies.
How can I make sure that I get at least some kind of brief information (in production) for every error that occurs when a custom policy is being called?
I already had a look into Application Insights technical profiles, but don't really think that it's something that could be used to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where/how was the correlationid generated?

Comment: The user was sent to a custom policy endpoint using a magic link and got the error message.

Comment: If anything, this will be inside the app insights logs. The failure here is not reported well, as it should never actually fail for a properly issued magic link and correctly configured policy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try to reproduce the issue in a test environment and check app insights logs there. But that will take some time as I need to gather more information. Coming back as soon as I managed to find out more.

Comment: You can open a support ticket with Microsoft and they can help more if the app insights show nothing.